# Could not load file or assembly. Signature has bad element type (HRESULT: 0x80131247)

Tags: assemblies, cil

I am trying to make a compiler to CIL (Microsoft IL). After the IL file is written, I generate the corresponding .exe file, using ilasm (CIL Assembler). After I tried to add generics, I get the following error when trying to run the executable:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'fungjprg, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Signature has bad element type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131247) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Signature has bad element type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131247)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I really do not understand where this is coming from, as everything used to work perfectly before trying to compile generic types. Moreover, as I though my IL code is bad, I wrote a simple generic program in C#, and took its generated IL (using ILDASM), and tried to run it, but I am getting the exact same error.

C# code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(new A<int>(3).f());
        }
    }

    class A<X>
    {
        X val;

        public A(X val)
        {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public X f()
        {
            return this.val;
        }
    }
```

My CIL file:

```
.assembly extern System.Runtime
{
.publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A)
.ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern System.Console
{
.publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A)
.ver 4:0:0:0
}

.assembly fungjprg 
{
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004 // I tried to add/remove this, same result...
  .ver 1:0:0:0 // I tried to add/remove this, same result...
}

.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit fungjprg.A`1<X>
       extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{

.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor(!X val) cil managed
{
  // Code size       16 (0x10)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  nop
  IL_0008:  ldarg.0
  IL_0009:  ldarg.1
  IL_000a:  stfld      !0 class fungjprg.A`1<!X>::val
  IL_000f:  ret
}

.method public hidebysig instance !X  f() cil managed
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (!X V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldfld      !0 class fungjprg.A`1<!X>::val
  IL_0007:  stloc.0
  IL_0008:  br.s       IL_000a
  IL_000a:  ldloc.0
  IL_000b:  ret
} 

}
.field private !X val

.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       19 (0x13)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0002:  newobj     instance void class fungjprg.A`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
  IL_0007:  call       instance !0 class fungjprg.A`1<int32>::f()
  IL_000c:  call       void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_0011:  nop
  IL_0012:  ret
}
```

ILASM output:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework IL Assembler.  Version 4.8.3752.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Assembling 'compiledprogram.fungj'  to EXE --> 'compiledprogram.exe'
Source file is ANSI

Assembled method fungjprg.A`1::.ctor
Assembled method fungjprg.A`1::f
compiledprogram.fungj(54) : warning : Non-static global field, made static
Assembled global method Main
Creating PE file

Emitting classes:
Class 1:        fungjprg.A`1

Emitting fields and methods:
Global  Fields: 1;      Methods: 1;
Class 1 Methods: 2;

Emitting events and properties:
Global
Class 1
Writing PE file
Operation completed successfully
```

I tried to sign the IL file with a strong name key, but the error still persists (the only difference is that the PublicKeyToken is not null anymore)

Comment: Does [PEVerify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/peverify-exe-peverify-tool) give you a more descriptive error?

Comment: [MD]: Error: Signature has invalid ELEMENT_TYPE_* (element type: 0x00000024; offset: 0x00000001). [token:0x04000001]
1 Error(s) Verifying compiledprogram.exe

Comment: Oh wait, your IL is for .NET Core, so maybe PEVerify won't work in that case. Are you running the app with the `dotnet` command?'

Comment: No, what would be the difference?

Comment: Well, for starters, .NET Core has a different distribution model, so I don't think an `.exe` is ever an assembly in those cases, but a native-to-each-OS executable that eventually calls out to the program's `.dll`. It seems that you're using the classic .NET Framework ILAsm, but your C# example decompiles as if it were a .NET Core app, because it references `System.Runtime` and `System.Console` instead of `mscorlib`. So maybe try compiling your C# code as a classic .NET Framework app, instead of a .NET Core app?

Comment: The same error occurs, whether I use .NET Core or .NET Framework..but yes, now I only reference mscorlib instead of System.Runtime and System.Console. But I think the key point is that this error does not occur for programs that don't use generics, could I maybe have overlooked something in that regard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218836/discussion-between-andreixwe-and-joe-sewell).

Comment: That warning is significant.  Variables and methods must be members of a class.  There is a "global" class, its name is `<Module>`.  Best not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

According your CIL file `.field private !X val` is not a part of class A. That's weird, because according to C# code it looks a part of it.

Try to move `.field private !X val` into the class scope, something like that

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit fungjprg.A`1<X>
   extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{

   .field private !X val

   .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
       instance void  .ctor(!X val) cil managed
   {
     // method code..
   }
}
```

Edit: I ran your CIL file with the fix and it works for me

Comment: I don't remember how I solved it and what exactly was the problem, but it was not working before the magic fix and it worked afterwards regardless of where that field was declared. But definitely, it's better to declare the field inside the class

Comment: Do you have an original command that you used with ilasm? I'm trying to understand what can be a cause for that case

Comment: Yes, `ilasm fileName [args]`